# Clusterization options for deep in-memory structures in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, load-balancing

We have a quite complex Java EE application (Java backend + GRails frontend communicating through Spring HTTP Invoker) with tons of horrible legacy code. Currently it runs in Jboss (will be migrated to Tomcat later).

In order to make it more reliable and increase performance we need to make it clusterable.

Problem is application currently has a lot of deep in-memory structures vital for whole business that need to be replicated (like domain objects inside of list inside of HashMap inside of ConcurrentHashMap inside of another ConcurrentHashMap).

As I said, there are lot of legacy code and we just cannot rework all of it.

Currently I'm playing with EHCache, but obviously without success - changes deep inside of cached objects are not replicated.

Terracotta DSO looks like something we should look into, but it's ultimate solution and I just don't want to introduce such radical solution while we have hope to solve it in more general way.

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis], but you probably meant [tag:cluster-computing] or [tag:load-balancing]!

Answer (score 1):

actually this is typical problem of most cashing solutions - working with deep in-memory structures and there no easy way to deal with this.

So for example lets take enterprise grid - **gigaspaces** - this is how it's done http://www.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP8/Modeling+your+data

This is really explain things around:

When Should Objects be Embedded?
You already know it's not a good practice to embed related objects. But even when there's a good case for embedding related objects (sometimes at the cost of data duplications), you still should be aware of the following:

Embedding means no direct access: When an entity is embedded within another entity you cannot apply CRUD operations to it directly. Instead, you need to get its root parent entity from the space via regualr query and then navigate down the object graph, until you get the entity you need. This is not just a matter of convenience, it has also performance implications: whenever you want to perform CRUD operations on an embedded entity, you read the entire graph first and (if you need to also update it) you write the entire object graph back to the Space.
On the other hand, with GigaSpaces non-embedded relationships mean you need to manage the relationship yourself, within your code.
Thumb Rules for Choosing Embedded Relationships
Embed when an entity is meaningful only with the context of its containing object. For example, in the petclinic application - a Pet has a meaning only when it has an Owner. A Pet in itself is meaningless without an Owner in this specific application. There is no business scenario for transferring a Pet from owner to owner or admitting a Pet to a Vet without the owner.
Embedding may sometimes mean duplicating your data. For example, if you want to reference a certain Visit from both the Pet and Vet class, you'll need to have duplicate Visit entries. So let's look into duplications:
Duplication means preferring scalability over footprint - the reason to duplicate is to avoid cluster wide transactions and in many cases it's the only way to partition your object in a scalable manner.
Duplication means higher memory consumption: While memory is considered a commodity and low cost today, duplication has a bigger price to pay - you might have two space objects that contain the same data.
Duplication means more lenient consistency. When you add a Visit to a Pet and Vet for example, you need to update them both. You can do it in one (potentially distributed) transaction, or in two separate transactions, which will scale better but be less consistent. This may be sufficient for many types of applications (e.g. social networks), where losing a post, although undesired, does not incur significant damage. In contrast, this is not feasible for financial applications where every operation should be accounted for.

In **hazelcast** you have a concept of data affinity http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/multi_html/ch03.html which is different from gigaspaces.

I mean that there is no simple solution and i guess you would need to re-desing your model anyway (doesn't matter whether this is coherence, gigaspaces, ehcache, hazelcast).